# Video is not uploading using http post request

Tags: android, video, androidhttpclient

I am trying to upload video to the server using http post request.

When I debug and see the http response it is showing 200 OK

My Service call

http://capmem.omsoftware.co/Event/UploadVideo?callback=localJsonpCallback&chunk=&totalSize=&Filename=&UserID=&EventID=&comment=&VideoLength=

but after this

```
String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
```

the responseStr returns {"Success":false,"Data":"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index","Message":"test","Id":0,"Email":null,"url":null,"imgurl":null}
 and video is not uploading.

My code

Getting video details

```
int mychunkSize = 100 * 1024;

            videoLength = String.format(
                    "%d min, %d sec",
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration)
                            - TimeUnit.MINUTES
                                    .toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
                                            .toMinutes(duration)));
            realPath = getRealPathFromURI(imageFileUri2);
            long size1 = realPath.length();
            size = Long.toString(size1);
            long chunks1 = size1 < mychunkSize ? 1
                    : (realPath.length() / mychunkSize);
            chunks = Long.toString(chunks1);
            file1 = new File(realPath);
            long length1 = file1.length();
            length1 = length1 / 1024;
            filename = file1.getName().toString();
            eventID = user.getnEventID();
            userID = user.getnUserID();
            commentMsg = "videotesting";
```

Upload to server

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(
                    HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

            entity.addPart("uploaded", new StringBody(realPath));

            HttpClient httpclient1 = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost1 = new HttpPost(
                    "http://capmem.omsoftware.co/Event/UploadVideo");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                        2);
                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("callback",
                        "localJsonpCallback"));
                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filename",
                        filename));
                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ext", "mp4"));

                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("totalsize",
                        size));

                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EventID",
                        eventID));
                nameValuePairs1
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", userID));

                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment",
                        commentMsg));
                nameValuePairs1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("VideoLength",
                        videoLength));
                nameValuePairs1
                        .add(new BasicNameValuePair("chunk", chunks));
                httppost1.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(
                        nameValuePairs1));
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient1.execute(httppost1);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (resEntity != null) {

                    String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity)
                            .trim();

                    // you can add an if statement here and do other actions
                    // based on the response
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
```

here "response" gives 200 OK, but
"responseStr" returns {"Success":false,"Data":"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index","Message":"test","Id":0,"Email":null,"url":null,"imgurl":null}

I need add chunks in loop with offset do it in loop till total size and offset will equal.

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

You're erroneously using the pathlength to calculate how many chunks of data to send.

Change this:

```
long chunks1 = size1 < mychunkSize ? 1
                : (realPath.length() / mychunkSize);
```

To:

```
long chunks1 = size1 < mychunkSize ? 1
                : (size1 / mychunkSize);
```

Comment: That is still not correct. And there is another unfinished thread about that issue.

Comment: I only posted what jumped out at me as wrong (it doesn't mean that the rest of the code is error free).  You're welcome to post your corrections...